# the mathematics of stirring

Tags: differential-topology, ergodic-theory

are there any resources on the mathematics of stirring let's say I stir a coffee cup with a spoon.  the result is a diffeomorphism from the disk to itself.  By physical intuition... that diffeomorphism should be mixing.

is there any way to formalize this reasoning?  I think it's not necessary to solve the Navier-Stokes equations.  Instead, we'd need to look at mixing diffeomorphisms of the disk.

---

my question is how is a stirring spoon mix?  the path is a circle - over and over.  And yet our coffee mixes.

Here is a picture of paint being stirred... obviously something is mixing.

[image]

Perhaps this question is ill-posed without a choice of physical model.

Comment: Of course you can model the movement of the coffee in a cup however you wish.  But a rigid rotation is a diffeomorphism that does not "mix", so some aspect of your modelling involves "mixing diffeomorphisms" that you haven't specified.  If by requesting resources "to formalize this reasoning" you want to avoid the Navier-Stokes equations, you'll need to give more details of what defines these mixing diffeomorphisms.

Comment: if I understood correctly you want to embed a line in an spiral in the plane. If you embed two orthogonal lines in two non-cutting spirals you can define an homeomorphism of the plane. The way you define the spirals is the way you want to model how the coffee stir.

Comment: Rotations of the disk are never topologically mixing, A better starting point are twist maps, provided that you like the condition of preserving the area (see http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symplectic_maps#Definition). Have a look say at https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org//index.php?title=Poincar%25C3%25A9_last_theorem&oldid=23480

Comment: I remembered a video from a fluid mechanics class where rotating concentric cylinders gave apparent mixing of the fluid between them, but when the motion of the cylinders reversed the result was "unmixing".  A similar effect is seen in this YouTube video, [Mixed fluid returns to its original state](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpJ-kGII074).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia: [Topological Fluid Dynamics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_fluid_dynamics)

> Problems of stirring and mixing are particularly susceptible to topological techniques. Thus, for example, the [Thurston–Nielsen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Thurston_classification) classification has been fruitfully applied to the problem of stirring in two-dimensions by any number of stirrers following a time-periodic 'stirring protocol' (Boyland, Aref & Stremler 2000).

I'd certainly like to know more.